# ¿cómo puedo "sintetizar" consultas de PHP a MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

debo acomodar por grupos y por tiempo a participantes de un juego al registrarse. esto quiere decir que cuando se llene el grupo1, te registrara en grupo2 y así sucesivamente. Tengo una columna llamada grupos_completos, la cual llene manualmente (para hacer el ejercicio), con  5 de grupo1 y 2 de grupo2.

```
   $resultado1 = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) grupos_completos FROM usuarios 
   WHERE grupos_completos ='grupo1';");
   $fila1 = $resultado1->fetch_row();
   echo $fila1[0];

   $resultado2 = $conexion->query("SELECT COUNT(*) grupos_completos FROM usuarios 
   WHERE grupos_completos ='grupo2';");
   $fila2 = $resultado2->fetch_row();
   echo $fila2[0];
```

Y luego quiero hacer un "if"

```
   if ($fila1[0] <= "4"){
      echo ("registra usuario en grupo1");
   } elseif ($fila2[0] <= "4") {
      echo ("registra usuario en grupo2");
   }
```

y así sucesivamente.
¿se puede realizar una sola consulta o debo hacer todas esas consultas? ¿para el "if" se puede hacer con una constante o hay otra forma?

Comment: Mírate la sintaxis de GROUP BY y podrás hacerlo en una sola consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola puedes sacar los datos de los dos grupos en una sola consulta. Solo tienes que agrupar la suma de jugadores (count) con un group by de la forma:

```
select grupos_completos, count(*) as total_jugadores from jugadores group by grupos_completos;
```

Te dejo aquí un [ejemplo online](https://sqltest.net/#1729220) para que lo pruebes/veas

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza una subconsulta, por ejemplo:

```
select (case when (select count(*) FROM usuarios WHERE grupos_completos ='grupo1') >= 5 then 'grupo2' else 'grupo1' end) as check_groups
```

Puedes hacer mas compleja la consulta si necesitas algo adicional